# Find the node with the minimum value in a graph

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, graph

There is a graph, nodes which are represented by objects:

```
Node = {
    value: <number>,
    children: [Node, Node ... Node] 
}
```

I need to find node with the minimum **value** field.

I have found the minimun value of the graph, but can't figure out how to return the **node**.

```
const min = (graph) => !graph.children ? graph.value :
    Math.min(graph.value, ...graph.children.map(min));
```

Example of the graph:

```
{value:31,children:[{value:68},{value:10,children:[{value:100,children:[{value:21,children:[{value:21},{value:64}]},{value:86}]}]}]}
```

Example of the answer:

```
{value:10,children:[{value:100,children:[{value:21,children:[{value:21},{value:64}]},{value:86}]}]}
```

Comment: do you have an example of the graph and the wanted result?

Comment: @NinaScholz the answer is the node with minimum value. In the example it is 10, so we return node with value 10 and all it's children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using reduce:

```js
function min(G){
  if (!G.children)
    return G
  else
    return G.children.reduce(function(acc, child){
      let minChild = min(child)
      if (minChild.value < acc.value)
        return minChild
      return acc
    }, G)
}

var G =  {value:31,children:[{value:68},{value:10,children:[{value:100,children:[{value:21,children:[{value:21},{value:64}]},{value:86}]}]}]}

console.log(JSON.stringify(min(G)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As possible solution, I suggest:

```
function min(graph){
    // the obvious case
    if(!graph.children){
        return graph;
    } 
    //get the min children 
    const comparator = (g1,g2)=>g1.value-g2.value; 
    //leaf ie node without children
    const leafs = graph.children.map(g=>min(g));
    leafs.sort(comparator); 
    return comparator(graph,leafs[0]) <= 0 ? graph : leafs[0];
}
```

This solution is available for limited graph, else you should change your structure to be more efficient for large graph.